# Redirect doesn't work even with any error

Tags: node.js

I want set up the log out in my application, but I'm stuck in redirecting the user to login form, knowing that it's an SPA.

here in my server.js i have

```
app.get('/logout',function(request, res){
    request.session.destroy();
    res.redirect('/');
    console.log("done");
});
```

and

```
app.get('/',function(request,response){
   response.sendFile("CERIGame/index.html",{ root: __dirname} );
});
```

just the login form is visible in the beginning.

and http request from where i call the "/logout" defined above

```
logOut: function(){
    return $http
    .get('/logout')
    .then(function(response){   
        logged = false;
        return "logging out";
    });
},
```

this http request defined in a factory.
the redirection to "/" doesn't work and it does not throw any exception, despite the console.log print the done message.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect an AJAX request? If you want to redirect the browser, you have to explicitly navigate to `/logout` in your browser so that it would get redirected to `/`. Otherwise, you have to handle redirection in the AJAX callback on the client side (e.g. call `location.assign("/")` within `.then()`).

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this as best as I can, your redirect is working correctly. The problem is the way you are making the request, when redirecting to `'/'` your `server.js` execute this action:

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile("CERIGame/index.html", { root: __dirname });
});
```

So far everything is fine, the reason why the form is not loading is because what is consuming the `server.js` is returning a `"logging out"`

```
logOut: function() {
    return $http
    .get('/logout')
    .then(function (response) {
        // Your form at this point is in response
        logged = false;
        return "logging out";
    });
},
```

Recapitulating the process in general if it is being carried out correctly, what is wrong is the implementation that makes the request to `/logout` since it is at this point where the form is lost to the final destination.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using Node.Js as the backend, AngularJs as front-end.

Back-end code will be

```
app.get('/logout',function(request, res){
  request.session.destroy();
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.send({success:true});
});
```

The front-end code will be

```
logOut: function(){
    return $http
    .get('/logout')
    .then(function(response){   
        //Here you can redirect in different ways like 
        window.location.href = '/';
        // or 
        /* $state.go('home'); //In case if you are using anuglar-ui router */
    });
},
```